# How to enlarge the storage size Azure SQL Database greater than 4 TB?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, size

We are in the process of developing a web application that we want to host on Azure, where the storage size of the SQL database database is expected to reach 100 TB.

The issue is the max size of the Azure SQL database is currently 4 TB which too small in our case.

Knowing the fact that we are using DTU pricing model, is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scale out by using SQL elastic pool. You will be using shard database, in other words creating different Azure SQL databases. Azure SQL elastic pool will make it easier to manage the database and query the data in a simple way using one Azure SQL Database elastic query.

I recommend reading the following documents from Microsoft docs:

[sql-database-elastic-scale-introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-introduction) 
[sql-database-elastic-scale-shard-map-management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-shard-map-management) 
[sql-database-elastic-query-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview)